# How can a set contain itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory

im reading a little about the Russell Paradox , and i dont really get what they mean by a set that contains itself , can anybody please explain ?

Comment: You can have a set of anything.  The set of animals in the world that are mammals.  Anything.  Consider a set where the elements are sets.  That set may contain itself.

Comment: A set that contains itself as an element. For example, let $S$ be the set of all sets that has at least one element. Does $S$ contain itself "as an element"? Yes, because $S$ contains at least one element!

Comment: isnt that wrong ? because the set of all sets doesnt exist

Comment: Modern set theory specifically refuses to let you do this to avoid things like russel's paradox.  But in my day we didn't have such hard rules.  Suppose you had the set of all infinite sets.  That set is infinite.  So that set is a member of the set.  Suppose you had the set of all sets.  That's a set.  So it is a member of the set.  Suppose you have a set of all finite sets.  That's infinite so it isn't in the set.  So suppose you have a set of all sets that do not have themselves as a member.

Comment: He didn't say the set of all sets.  He said the set of all sets that have more than one members.  And what do you mean the set of all sets doesn't exist?  Where did you hear that and why do you think it is true?

Comment: @Carser: No, a set can't be 'anything'.  In fact, Russell's Paradox is a demonstration of this.  If you allow yourself to define sets with no restrictions you run into paradoxes.

Comment: @fleablood I heard that some things were just too big to be elements of sets, in which case these big things cannot be sets as otherwise they would then be elements of their own power sets

Comment: It depends on your axioms and what set theory you are using.  If you are not using Zarmelo Fraenkal you can.  Otherwise you can't.

Comment: @JairTaylor Of course a set can't be just anything... I didn't say a set can be anything.  I'm addressing the common misconception that sets are only of numbers by pointing out you can have a set of different classes of objects, e.g., mammals.

Comment: Ah, I see now that you mean 'a set can have anything as an element' not 'a set can be anything'.  Still, I think this is misleading.  In the usual formation of set theory elements of sets are themselves sets, not things like animals.  The integers, real numbers, etc. are all specific constructed out of sets like the empty set $\emptyset$, the set $\{\emptyset\}$, etc.

Comment: @Henry I was goading you.  And why shouldn't things be elements of their own power set?  The point is modern set theory (ZF) modified axioms to avoid the inconsistancies and paradoxes of earlier set theory of the sort Russell would  have been using.  A set in it's most basic definition is a collection.  And there is nothing poorly defined or inconsistent with a collection including itself as a member.   One might intuitively thing that means a circular construction but it doesn't as "the set of all sets" and "the set of all infinite/finite sets" are perfectly well-defined....

Comment: ...  so we can have the set of sets that do not have themselves as a member and that set is unclassifiable (if it has itself as a member then it doesn't and if it doesn't it does) showing the system of set theory that Russell was using was inconsistent.  Modern ZF theory however simply says we can't do that.

Comment: @fleablood: I knew

Answer (score 2):

There are two different issues here with two different answers.

One is: Can a set have itself as an element?  This would be a pretty strange set.  One could imagine something like $\{\{ \cdots \{1 \}  \cdots \} \}$, with infinitely many brackets.  But just because I write this down doesn't mean it makes sense.  Whether or not you allow something like this depends on your choice of axioms of set theory.  The most common formalization of set theory, [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), does not allow this due to the Axiom of Regularity.  Almost all of math research can be formalized in ZFC, so for the most part you will never see sets that contain themselves.  (Maybe they are useful somehow in other axiom systems - I don't know.)

The other issue is: Does the set $$\{S \,|\, S \notin S\}$$ make sense?  Evidently, the answer is no, because here is where we run into Russell's Paradox.  But the issue is perhaps not what you might think it is.  For example, if you don't believe in complex numbers, then there is no number $x$ with $x^2 = -1$.  However, you can still write the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | x^2 = -1\}$.  You just get the empty set.  So it's not a problem to write things like $S \in S$ or $S \notin S$.  It's just the first one will always be false, and the second always true, if you're in the context of ZFC.

The problem is that there is no restriction to what sets the variable $S$ is allowed to run over.  If we start with a given set of sets $\mathcal{F}$ and write $\{ S \in \mathcal{F} | S \notin S\}$ we don't have any problems.  It's okay that we are writing $S \notin S$.  For example let $\mathcal{F} = \{ \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{5,6\} \}$.  There's no element of $\mathcal{F}$ that's an element of itself.  So, $\{ S \in \mathcal{F} | S \notin S\}  = \{ \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{5,6\} \}$.  You have $\mathcal{F} \notin \mathcal{F}$, but this does *not* mean that $\mathcal{F} \in \{S \in \mathcal{F}| S \notin S\}$.  Why?  Because the elements $S$ of $\{ S \in \mathcal{F} |S \notin S\}$ are specifically restricted to be elements of $\mathcal{F}$, so $\mathcal{F}$ is not under consideration in the definition - just like $i$ is not an element of $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x^4 = 1\}$ since by definition every element of $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x^4 = 1\}$ is real.

The paradox arises where we allow a set $U$ to be the "set of all sets". Then since $U$ is a set, $U \in U$.  Furthermore, if such a set $U$ exists, then the set $\{S \in U | S \notin S\}$ makes perfect sense and we get Russell's Paradox. Suddenly the world implodes: every logical statement can be proven true.

tl;dr version: In the usual formulation of set theory, sets can't contain themselves, and you can't have a set of all sets, but restricted sets like $\{S \in \mathcal{F}| S \notin S\}$ are fine.

Comment: "Can a set have itself as an element? This would be a pretty strange set."  Not in the least!  The set of sets isn't seem strange.  Nor does the set of infinite sets.  It only seems strange if we deconstruct it and list it by it's elements and its elements by its elements and get an infinite regress but there's utterly no reason we *should* be able to deconstruct sets this way.  We can't deconstruct uncountable sets after all.  However it does prove our system is inconsistent.  So we use ZF... which is incomplete because we *can't* say perfectly normal things like the set of all sets.

Comment: Also, a universal set isn't necessary for Russel's paradox to rear its head. They're quite distinct issues.

Comment: @fleablood Hmm, I could see where "the set of all sets" would seem pretty useful, but I think if you point out to someone that it has itself as an element they will probably agree this is a rather strange property for a set to have.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine This isn't really my area, so perhaps you are right.  But how  can Russell's Paradox arise without the set of all sets?  It seems to me that if your rules of set formation allow things like $\{S | S \notin S\}$ then they should also allow things like $\{S | S = S\}$ which would be the set of all sets.  But I am probably missing something here.

Comment: @JairTaylor - Well, as a silly example, take the theory whose only axioms are extensionality and the existence of $\{x:x\notin x\}$. There's no proof, without employing *ex falso*, of the existence of a universal set. It really depends on the details of the comprehension scheme.

Comment: Russell ' s paradox was a demonstration that set theory as it existed then was inconsistent.  ZF has more axioms that among other things do not allow sets to contain themselves as members.  Russell paradox can not happen in ZF because collections with themselves as members aren't sets.  This may be for the besy, But ZF is a choice of axioms.   If you choose other axioms, as Russell did, you get other results.

Comment: With ZF you can have sets of sets.  You just can't have sets of sets that have itself as members.  So you can not have a set of all sets.  Or a set of all infinite sets.  But you can have the set of all finite sets.  Which strikes me as ... incomplete but... them's the breaks.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Hmm... that's not very satisfying.  Is there a less silly example?  It seems to me that unrestricted quantification is the main root of the problem here.

Comment: @fleablood It doesn't seem incomplete to me (unless you mean in the technical sense of the Incompleteness Theorems).  The set of all sets seems to me like a pretty weird set to me, a sort of nightmarish creature to be avoided at all cost :)

Comment: I was mostly joking and obliquely referring to incompleteness theorems.  It does seem odd that the set of finite sets is a set but the set of infinite sets, which seems perfectly conceivable, is not.

Comment: I can't think of a less silly example off hand, and that's likely because we knew better pretty quickly. NF set theory, however, is an example showing that a universal set and unrestricted quantification in the comprehension schemes are not the issue.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Ah, I was not familiar with NF. You have a good point.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for stating the Axiom of Regularity. Exactly the reference I have been looking for.

Comment: This question is ancient, but, just for posterity, the set of all finite sets is not a set in ZFC either.  If it were, you could take its union and get the set of all sets, since it would contain all the singletons $\{S\}$.